# Referencing-values-with-refs Challenge 3: Fix Debouncing

Tags: reactjs

On the React official docs (react.dev); referencing values with refs, challenge 3: Fix debouncing, https://react.dev/learn/referencing-values-with-refs

The solution uses useRef on the timeoutID and places the ref inside the DebouncedButton component.

When I first solved it, I literally just declared the variable inside the component (i.e moved `let timeoutID;` into the DebouncedButton component) so that each button has its own timeoutID that gets cleared when the button is clicked.

It behaves exactly like the provided solution using refs.

My question is why should I use refs and not my initial solution? what am I missing?